# find HTML Title from Delphi "Web Server Application"

Tags: javascript, html, delphi, web, cgi

With delphi7 i create "Web Server Application" (MyCGI.EXE), some procedure in there to serve client.

Client Web based HTML (MyHTML.HTML) call javascript (AJAX) (MyScript.js) to open MyCGI.EXE and receive "response" from server.

And all there is work.

Because i must include client source code (MyHTML.HTML, Myscript.JS) but not Server source code, i want server can filter if user change title of MyHTML.HTML, if title of myHtml changed then server will not send "response".

In MyCgi I try "request.title" but the result is empty.

So any idea or solution "How my server find MyHTMl.html "Title" form server (MyCgib)?

thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server does not have access to the contents of any page on the client responsible for initiating the request. The server only knows what the client tells it, and you can observe that page title is not ordinarily included in any HTTP requests.

If the server needs to know the title of the page, then you need to make sure that's one of the parameters the client sends with its request. You cannot enforce that it's really the title of the page, though; nothing prevents the client from lying to the server. It can have whatever title it wants, as long as it uses the right magic words in its request to make the server think it has a required title.

Comment: Thank Rob for ur answer its explain why i can't access client content from server. Can filter by HTML Title from web server (Apache) ?